# Nginx escaping ampersand

Tags: nginx, query-string, ampersand, proxypass

So I have this encoded URL http://localhost:3050/pdfx/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpdf.html%3FlipperId%3D61%26lang%3Dfr-ca

that translates to http://localhost:3050/pdfx/http:/localhost/pdf.html?lipperId=61&lang=fr-ca

my nginx.conf is the following

```
http{
server {
    listen 3050 default_server;
    listen [::]:3050 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root C:\Workspaces\wmsi_workspace\pdf-renderer;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;


   location ~ ^/pdfx/(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://node_phantomjs_server_standard?site=$1;
   }

   location ~ ^/pdfxi/ {
      proxy_pass http://node_phantomjs_server_inject;
   }

   location ~ ^/api/rps {
      proxy_pass http://node_phantomjs_server_inject;
   }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 500 502 503 504 /index.html;

}

upstream node_phantomjs_server_standard {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream node_phantomjs_server_inject {
  server 127.0.0.1:3050;
}
```

}

When I hit the URL above it gets translated to http://localhost/pdf.html?lipperId=61 and completely ignores the filter part of the querystring (not a legit querystring).

I'm not sure why this is happening as it always skips the ampersand and what follows it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing the URL from the command line, the issue is that '&' is a special character to the `bash` shell. That would be solved by wrapping the URL in single quotes.

If you are not testing from the command line, the translation could be related to a browser. Try testing from the command-line for an alternate perspective:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3050/pdfx/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fpdf.html%3FlipperId%3D61%26lang%3Dfr-ca'
```

Comment: I'm actually testing it from the browser, so I can't wrap it in single quotes but will have it mind if I encounter a situation like this. Other situation to overcome this(not sure if that's the best practice) is to double encode the '&' and only it out of the whole url to be like %2526, doing this was making the url parsed completely and correctly.

Comment: Double-encoding could be appropriate here because you are passing a URL in a URL.